# Using multiple features in matalbs trainNetwork to determine an artist of a painting

Tags: image-processing, machine-learning, conv-neural-network

I am using convolutional neural networks to discriminate who is the artist of a painting. I have around 200 images from each artist, all resized to the same size and rgb (so 3 separate color channels). 90% of the images are used as training images and the rest for testing.

When I use trainNetwork I get around 70% accuracy (± 5%). It fluctuates since the selection of the training data i random.

Is it possible to better the accuracy with more "features"? Lets say I use imgradient to find the magnitude and direction of an image. I can use these two separately to train my CNN (just like I would with my original images but magnitude and direction are 2-dimensional data) and I will get different results from using the rgb images. But is it possible to use all 3 in combination to better the accuracy somehow? I hope the question is understandable.

Here is my code if it is needed. I have used this example as a template: https://se.mathworks.com/help/nnet/ref/trainnetwork.html

```
% Reading the images
digitDatasetPath = fullfile(pwd ,'images', 'NOF', 'XXS');
digitData = imageDatastore(digitDatasetPath,...
        'IncludeSubfolders',true,'LabelSource','foldernames');
% Defining the training and testing data
trainingNumFiles = 0.9;
rng(1) % For reproducibility
[trainDigitData,testDigitData] = splitEachLabel(digitData,...
                trainingNumFiles, 'randomize');
% Read the size of the image
[n, m, o] = size(digitData.readimage(1));
% Defining the layers
layers = [imageInputLayer([n m o]);
          convolution2dLayer(5,20);
          reluLayer();
          maxPooling2dLayer(2,'Stride',2);
          fullyConnectedLayer(2);
          softmaxLayer();
          classificationLayer()];

% Setting the training options
options = trainingOptions('sgdm','MaxEpochs',20,...
    'InitialLearnRate',0.0001, 'ExecutionEnvironment', 'parallel');
% Starting the training
convnet = trainNetwork(trainDigitData,layers,options);
% Testing the result
YTest = classify(convnet,testDigitData);
TTest = testDigitData.Labels;
% Print the result
accuracy = sum(YTest == TTest)/numel(TTest)
% Notify!
beep on
beep'
```

Edit: Adding the data printed during the training:

[Data printed during the training](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZkHLm.png)

Comment: The 70% is the test error or train error? Also I suggest to add a validation group.

Comment: It is the test error. How do I add a validation group?

Comment: Validation group is a subset of your train images. What is your train error? if the train error is very and you validation error and test error are high you are overfitting your data you need to train with more regularization like dropout etc. If the validation error is also low but the test is high you need to get more data for the training or change your network design, i.e add more layers etc...

Comment: According to this link the trainDigitData is the called validation. Is it maybe build into CNN? https://se.mathworks.com/help/vision/examples/image-category-classification-using-deep-learning.html In NN the data is actually split into three parts and validation is one of them. I have also added the printed data during the training. It think minibatch accuracy is the validation and it seems pretty good, dont you think? Can I add my own filters or can I only use the predefined matlab ones? I mean if I want to do a fouriertransform and use that data in the CNN, can that be considered as a filter?